# link task to list item

Tags: task-list, list-item, links

how can I link task to list item. I need to link between the related content field from task list and Name (linked to document with edit menu) field from the list itself. I need to email the subordinate that is exist in task list. I did the below and I tried to print it in an email and it shows empty value. nothing is there, for that it is not sending any emails to the subordinate.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change the return field as "Email address" ?

Comment: yes I did, still not working @SohailShaikh

Comment: What is stored in the "Related Content" field in Tasks List??

Comment: @GaneshSanap the list item Name

Comment: Is it stored as a name or as lookup to the list item(with ID)?

Comment: as name. I have a question if you can help on that. the subordinate , assign to and other people picker fields in the approval form. It is possible to use them with multiple users. Like I assign task to 5 people and it goes once to them. Because currently it goes to the first entered user only. Keep in mind that I checked the option of allow multiple selections in the form and the list. @GaneshSanap

Answer (score 0):

This is because the work email or email address is not associated in the AD or User Profile Service with that value of "Subordinate".

Please check with other Subordinate values.

Comment: no it is from AD. when I go to task list I can see the name there in subordinate. put when I did as the screenshot to send him email. No approval task will go to him and the workflow status will be completed.

Comment: @Arwa It is associated with the "email address" and not the name.

Comment: so what can I do. Actually the subordinate field is a customization of an approval form. for that I need to get the names from the task list, but it is not working @Sohail Shaikh

Comment: @Arwa Are you using SP 2013 workflow? If yes, is the User Profile Service configured running?

Comment: yes it is 2013 and the User Profile Service already configured

Comment: @Arwa Is the issue persist with specific users or all users?

Comment: It is with all users @ Sohail Shaikh